# How DataSourceAttribute Works

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, datasource

I have defined a DataSource to specific table as in the next code:

```
[DataSource("System.Data.Odbc",
"Dsn=R10;Uid=sa;Pwd=Abcd1234@;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True;",
"Products",
 DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
```

When the datasource gets the data from table, does it upload to the cache all the rows of the table or the datasource works with bulks.

If it does work with bulks, is there a way to control on the bulk size?

Comment: datasource for what? Grid?

Comment: How is your question related to unit testing?

Comment: That is the `[DataSourceAttribute]` decorating a `[TestMethod]` to determine how many times the test will run, and with which parameters (from the data source).

Answer (score 1):

[According to documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.webtesting.datasourceattribute.aspx), entire data set is loaded before any test is run:

> The data source cannot be changed based on input during a test because all the data is loaded and cached before the first test runs.